# Is there any way to generate a pdf in Struts 1.x with latex code?

Tags: eclipse, pdf, latex, struts, birt

I have been searching for a way to generate a pdf inside Struts 1.x and it occurs to me that it would be awesome to use latex code to include style on the pdf. Is this possible? I thought of [birt](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/) and eclipse but I haven't been able to find any libraries that allow this.